# Django prevent default permissions

Tags: python, django

```
class Product(BaseModel):   
    code = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    --

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'products' 
        permissions = (("can_create_product", "Can create product"),                       
                       ("can_edit_product", "Can edit product"),)


class Product_stock(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    warehouse = models.ForeignKey(Warehouse_list)
    stock = models.FloatField(validators = [MinValueValidator(0.0)])

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'product_stocks'
```

In second model I don't want permissions. but django create three default permissions for that. How can I prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the rules behind [Meta inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#meta-inheritance).

You should do this inside of your `Product_stock` model:

```
class Meta:
    db_table = 'product_stocks' 
    permissions = ()
```

This should override the Meta permissions inherited from your super-model.

Comment: This method does not work at least as of Django 2.2. I believe now the `permissions` attribute of `Meta` just exists for adding additional custom permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is and old question, but here are my 2 cents for anyone new seeing this, according to Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#default-permissions) you can override default model permissions like this:

```
class Meta:
    db_table = 'product_stocks'
    default_permissions = ()
```